# Java Inheritance and Polymorphism Program

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I am new to Java and have most likely made a stupid mistake on my code.  In particular, I am having problems with the main arguments, asking for and saving scanner objects to link to the other subclasses.  I believe that the Person, Student, Employee, Faculty, and Staff portions are correct but I cannot figure out the Driver portion. Below is the homework problem.  Thank you in advance for any help or advice!

HOMEWORK PROBLEM:
Design a class named  Person and its two subclasses, Student and Employee. Make Faculty and Staff subclasses of Employee.

A Person object  has a name , address, phone number, and email address (all Strings ).

A Student has a class  status (freshman, sophomore, junior, or senior). Define the status as a final String  variable .

An Employee has an office number , salary (both ints ), and a date hired. Use the MyDate class  defined below to create an object  for date hired:

```
class  MyDate{
private  String  date; //date in the form mm/dd/yy

public MyDate(String  date){
this.date = date;
}

public String  getDate(){
return date;
}
}
```

A Faculty object  has office hours and a rank (both Strings ), while a Staff object  has a title (as a String ).

For the Student, Faculty, and Staff classes, create toString methods  that store  information about the object  (in the format shown in the examples below).

Test your classes in a Driver class  (within the same file) that asks the user what type  of object  they'd to create as well as what information they'd like it to have.
The program  then uses the object 's toString method  to print information about that object .
Sample Run #1

Enter 
1)To create a student 
2)To create an employee:  1
Enter  name :  Walter D. Graham
Enter address:  4737 Stadium Drive Whitinsville, MA 01588
Enter phone number:  508-266-2108
Enter email:  walterdgraham@university.edu
Enter student's status:  Junior
Student: Walter D. Graham 
Status: Junior 
Address: 4737 Stadium Drive Whitinsville, MA 01588 
Phone Number: 508-266-2108 
Email Address: walterdgraham@university. edu
Sample Run #2

Enter 
1)To create a student 
2)To create an employee:  2
Enter  name :  Kimberly D. Davis
Enter address:  795 University Hill Road Decatur, IL 62522
Enter phone number:  217-519-6747
Enter email:  kimdavis@school.edu
Enter 
1)To create a faculty member 
2)To create a staff member:  1
Enter office number:  724
Enter salary:  84101
Enter date hired (mm/ dd/ yy):  06/12/92
Enter office hours:  5-7pm, Mon-Thu
Enter rank:  Adjunct Professor
Faculty: Kimberly D. Davis 
Rank: Adjunct Professor 
Salary: $84101 
Date Hired: 06/12/92

Office Hours: 5-7pm, Mon-Thu 
Office: 724 
Address: 795 University Hill Road Decatur, IL 62522 
Phone Number: 217-519-6747 
Email: kimdavis@school. edu

DRIVER PORTION THAT I WROTE:

```
package person;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Driver {
//Testing

public static void main(String[] args) {

int studentOrEmployee;
int facultyOrStaff;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter");
System.out.println("1)To create a student:");
System.out.print("2)To create and employee: ");
studentOrEmployee= input.nextInt();

System.out.print("\n Enter name: ");
Person name = input.next();
System.out.print("\n Enter address: ");
Person address = input.nextString();
System.out.print("\n Enter phone number: ");
Person phone = input.nextString();
System.out.print("\n Enter email ");
Person email = input.nextString();

if (studentOrEmployee==1) {
System.out.print("\n Enter student’s status: ");
Person classStanding = input.nextString();
System.out.println(student.toString() + "\n");
}

else if ( studentOrEmployee==2) {

facultyOrStaff= input.nextInt();
if (facultyOrStaff==1) {
System.out.print("\nEnter office number: ");
Person office = input.nextInt();
System.out.print("\nEnter salary");
Person salary = input.nextInt();
System.out.print("\nEnter date hired: ");
Person dateHired = input.next();
System.out.print("\nEnter office hours: ");
Person hours = input.nextString();
System.out.print("\nEnter rank: ");
Person rank = input.nextString();
System.out.println(faculty.toString() + "\n"); 
}   
else if (facultyOrStaff==2) {
System.out.print("\nEnter office number: ");
System.out.print("\nEnter office title: ");
Person title = input.nextString();
System.out.println(staff.toString() + "\n");
}
}
Person person = new Person(name,address, phone, email);
Person student = new Student(name, classStanding, address, phone, email);
Person employee = new Employee(name, address, phone, email, office, salary, dateHired);
Person faculty = new Faculty(name, rank, salary, dateHired, hours, address, phone, email, office);
Person staff = new Staff(name, title, address, phone, email, office, salary, dateHired);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you construct a [**m**cve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us, please?

Comment: I don't know how to answer this question in its current form.  What actual problem are you having?

Comment: The program is not accepting the scanner inputs: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to person.Person
 at person.Driver.main(

Answer (score 0):

check your declaration. If you wanted to save a String you need to declare your variable as a String.

```
System.out.print("\n Enter name: ");
String name = input.next();
System.out.print("\n Enter address: ");
String address = input.nextString();
System.out.print("\n Enter phone number: ");
String phone = input.nextString();
System.out.print("\n Enter email ");
String email = input.nextString();
....
```